# Serialize Android view to xml layout

Tags: android, xml, serialization, layout

It's quite easy to create view from xml layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

But the question is how to save content view to xml layout?
So i can take a snapshot of my UI when app is running

Comment: I believe there is no such convenient mean to do so. However I expect to see if someone has any clever trick to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you start emulator and open Devices property in top bar in last camer option is there you can capture you layout photo ....